# how can I change the text after getting the value from the method after clicking the button

Tags: flutter, dart

As soon as I click the button called *GET LOCATION AGAIN*, I get the value and assign those values to the global variable of latitude and longitude, but at the same time, i want to change the text field of *latitude* and *longitude* once I click the *Get LOCATION AGAIN BUTTON* because as soon as I get this page, sometimes I can't get the location values. 
 How do I do that?

```
 void getLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    longitude = position.longitude;
    latitude = position.latitude;
    print("latitude :" + latitude.toString());
    print("longitude :" + longitude.toString());
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        title: Text("Location Sender"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            child: Icon(Icons.search),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(
                "ID: ${widget.id}",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
              ),
              new Text(
                "DESCRIPTION: ${widget.desc}",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
              ),
              new Text(
                "LATITUDE: ${latitude != null ? latitude.toString() : '0'}",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
              ),
              new Text(
                "LONGITUDE: ${longitude != null ? longitude.toString() : '0'}",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 150,
              ),
              new ListTile(
                title: new RaisedButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                  textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: new Text("GET LOCATION AGAIN"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    getLocation();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              new ListTile(
                title: new RaisedButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                  textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: new Text("POST LOCATION"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    sendRequest(id, description, latitude, longitude);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use setState method, it will rebuild your widget once lat long is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* use setState((){}) .. it's recreate the build(context).
* Your class should be extends StatefulWidget not StatelessWidget

void getLocation() async {
  Position position = await Geolocator()
    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  setState((){
    longitude = position.longitude;
  latitude = position.latitude;
  });
  print("latitude :" + latitude.toString());
  print("longitude :" + longitude.toString());
 }
```

Happy Coding.... :))

Answer (score 1):

use setState():

```
 void getLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    setState(() {
          longitude = position.longitude;
          latitude = position.latitude;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use setState method, it will rebuild your widget once LAT,LON is loaded.. update below code inside getlocation method

```
setState(() {
          longitude = position.longitude;
          latitude = position.latitude;
    });
```